# Why is $\max \{ | a_{i,j}| : 1 \le i \le m, 1 \le j \le n \} \le \sup \{||Ax|| : ||x|| = 1\}$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

This is an inequality on the operator norm, but I cannot understand why it's true.

Why is $\max\{|a_{i,j}| : 1 \le i \le m, 1 \le j \le n\} \le \sup\{||Ax|| : ||x|| = 1\}$?

That is, why is the absolute value of the largest element of $A$ lesser than or equal to the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $i_0$, choosing the vector $e_{i_0}$, which is admissible as its norm is $1$, the right hand side is
$$\|Ae_{i_0}\|=\sqrt{\sum_j (a_{i_0j})^2}\geq\sqrt{a_{i_0j_0}^2}=|a_{i_0j_0}|,\ \forall\ j_0$$
where the middle equality follows from the monotonicity of the square root.

Comment: What definition for matrix norm is this? And shouldn't $\sup || Ae_{i_{0}}|| = \max_{i} \lambda_i$?

Comment: I used the definition you gave, nothing else.

Comment: I didn't give a particular matrix norm definition. But I assume that it's the euclidean norm. But $A$ is also not said to necessarily be a square matrix.

Comment: Also is $e_{i_0}$ a standard basis vector?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a standard basis vector.

Comment: But are all $||x||=1$ vectors necessarily standard basis vectors?

Comment: No. There is a whole sphere of such vectors.

Comment: But is it then not a problem that you're displaying the proof "only" for standard basis vectors?